# Export a large CSV file in parallel to SQL server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, multithreading, csv

I have a large CSV file... 10 columns, 100 million rows, roughly 6 GB in size on my hard disk.
I want to read this CSV file line by line and then load the data into a Microsoft SQL server database using SQL bulk copy.
I have read couple of threads on here and also on the internet. Most people suggest that reading a CSV file in parallel doesn't buy much in terms of efficiency as the tasks/threads contend for disk access.

What I'm trying to do is, read line by line from CSV and add it to blocking collection of size 100K rows. And once this collection is full spin up a new task/thread to write the data to SQL server using SQLBuckCopy API.

I have written this piece of code, but hitting an error at run time that says "Attempt to invoke bulk copy on an object that has a pending operation." This scenario looks like something that can be easily solved using .NET 4.0 TPL but I'm not able to get it work. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

```
    public static void LoadCsvDataInParalleToSqlServer(string fileName, string connectionString, string table, DataColumn[] columns, bool truncate)
    {
        const int inputCollectionBufferSize = 1000000;
        const int bulkInsertBufferCapacity = 100000;
        const int bulkInsertConcurrency = 8;

        var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        var sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnection.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock)
        {
            EnableStreaming = true,
            BatchSize = bulkInsertBufferCapacity,
            DestinationTableName = table,
            BulkCopyTimeout = (24 * 60 * 60),
        };

        BlockingCollection<DataRow> rows = new BlockingCollection<DataRow>(inputCollectionBufferSize);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(table);
        dataTable.Columns.AddRange(columns);

        Task loadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in ReadRows(fileName, dataTable))
                {
                    rows.Add(row);
                }

                rows.CompleteAdding();
            });

        List<Task> insertTasks = new List<Task>(bulkInsertConcurrency);

        for (int i = 0; i < bulkInsertConcurrency; i++)
        {
            insertTasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew((x) =>
                {
                    List<DataRow> bulkInsertBuffer = new List<DataRow>(bulkInsertBufferCapacity);

                    foreach (DataRow row in rows.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                    {
                        if (bulkInsertBuffer.Count == bulkInsertBufferCapacity)
                        {
                            SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = x as SqlBulkCopy;
                            var dataRows = bulkInsertBuffer.ToArray();
                            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataRows);
                            Console.WriteLine("Inserted rows " + bulkInsertBuffer.Count);
                            bulkInsertBuffer.Clear();
                        }

                        bulkInsertBuffer.Add(row);
                    }

                },
                sqlBulkCopy));
        }

        loadTask.Wait();
        Task.WaitAll(insertTasks.ToArray());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<DataRow> ReadRows(string fileName, DataTable dataTable)
    {
        using (var textFieldParser = new TextFieldParser(fileName))
        {
            textFieldParser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            textFieldParser.Delimiters = new[] { "," };
            textFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

            while (!textFieldParser.EndOfData)
            {
                string[] cols = textFieldParser.ReadFields();

                DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();

                for (int i = 0; i < cols.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cols[i]))
                    {
                        row[i] = DBNull.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row[i] = cols[i];
                    }
                }

                yield return row;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of spending time writing your own tool, why not use an ETL tool that already does this such as SQL Server Integration Services.

Comment: Have you tried a sequential version of this code and have you proven the complication of multi-threading is worth the performance gain?

Comment: There are many online guides for optimizing bulk inserts, i.e. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190421(v=sql.105).aspx. It sounds like you are trying to solve a problem that you haven't proven exists. I suggest you first get a baseline simply using `BCP.EXE` and then try and improve on that time.

Comment: From what I read online...SqlBulkCopy is much faster than the inbuilt data import tool that SQL server has which I believe uses SSIS under the covers. Load performance is critical and hence my investigation on writing my own lil app for it

Comment: I had similar volumes and in my case the Disk IO of my SQL server was the bottleneck so I did split the batches up but I did not go parrallel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't.

Parallel access may or may not give you faster read of the file (it won't, but I'm not going to fight *that* battle...) but for certain parallel writes it won't give you faster bulk insert. That is because minimally logged bulk insert (ie. the *really fast* bulk insert) requires a table lock. See [Prerequisites for Minimal Logging in Bulk Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422.aspx):

> Minimal logging requires that the target table meets the following conditions:
>
> ...
>   - **Table locking is specified (using TABLOCK)**.
>   ...

Parallel inserts, by definition, cannot obtain concurrent table locks. QED. You are barking up the wrong tree.

Stop getting your sources from random finding on the internet. Read [The Data Loading Performance Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=sql.100).aspx), is *the* guide to ... performant data loading.

I would recommend to you stop inventing the wheel. Use an [SSIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx), this is *exactly* what is designed to handle.

Comment: Ok. Can you point me to an existing SSIS package that bulk inserts data from a csv file into a SQL table? I don't want to re-invent the wheel as you said and so would like to use some pre-existing solution instead of creating ssis package on my own

Comment: All you need is a [Flat File Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139941.aspx) connected to a [OleDB Destination](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141237.aspx) with fast-load set. See [Import CSV File into Database Table Using SSIS](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/12/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-database-table-using-ssis/), for example.

Comment: >> but for certain parallel writes it won't give you faster bulk insert. <<

This is not true. I used something similar, PowerShell runspaces, with table locking, and I went from 90,000 rows/sec to 140,000 rows/sec.

Answer (score 5):

http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/

If possible for you, I suggest you read your file into a List<T> using the aforementioned csvhelper and write to your db using bulk insert as you are doing or efbulkinsert which I have used and is amazingly fast.

```
using CsvHelper;

public static List<T> CSVImport<T,TClassMap>(string csvData, bool hasHeaderRow, char delimiter, out string errorMsg) where TClassMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvClassMap
    {
        errorMsg = string.Empty;
        var result = Enumerable.Empty<T>();

        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvData));
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memStream);
        var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader);

        csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TClassMap>();
        csvReader.Configuration.DetectColumnCountChanges = true;
        csvReader.Configuration.IsHeaderCaseSensitive = false;
        csvReader.Configuration.TrimHeaders = true;
        csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = delimiter.ToString();
        csvReader.Configuration.SkipEmptyRecords = true;
        List<T> items = new List<T>();

        try
        {
            items = csvReader.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            while (ex != null)
            {
                errorMsg += ex.Message + Environment.NewLine;

                foreach (var val in ex.Data.Values)
                    errorMsg += val.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;

                ex = ex.InnerException;
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Edit - I don't understand what you are doing with the bulk insert.  You want to bulk insert the whole list or data data table, not row-by-row.

Comment: The csv seems to be very large. (6 GB). Does the `GetRecords<T>().ToList()` load everything to the memory ?

Comment: yes - good point, it may not be possible for him.  BulkInserting in one gulp is a big timesaver tho.  Perhaps he can call Take() on the list to chunk it up a bit.  His list seems to fit into a string created by File.ReadLines.

Comment: I can't load the whole csv file in memory because of the size. So I need to read 100K lines at a time and then write it to SQL server using bulkinsert. And yes, I do want to write the whole table at once not one row at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You can create store procedure and pass the file location like below

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CSVReaderTransaction]
    @Filepath varchar(100)=''
AS
-- STEP 1: Start the transaction
BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- STEP 2 & 3: checking @@ERROR after each statement
EXEC ('BULK INSERT Employee FROM ''' +@Filepath
        +''' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'' )')

-- Rollback the transaction if there were any errors
IF @@ERROR <> 0
 BEGIN
    -- Rollback the transaction
    ROLLBACK

    -- Raise an error and return
    RAISERROR ('Error in inserting data into employee Table.', 16, 1)
    RETURN
 END

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

You can also add BATCHSIZE option like FIELDTERMINATOR and ROWTERMINATOR.

Comment: doesnt work for me coz the file is on my local machine and the SQL server is on a different machine and that machine doesn't have remote access to my local drive